# Circular reference when using JSON-log-formatter with websockets

Tags: python, json, logging, websocket

I'm using JSON-log-formatter to print log messages in JSON format.

I'm getting the error:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1083, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 927, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\json_log_formatter\__init__.py", line 71, in format
    return self.to_json(mutated_record)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\json_log_formatter\__init__.py", line 84, in to_json
    return self.json_lib.dumps(record, default=_json_serializable)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
ValueError: Circular reference detected
```

Digged a bit and I've found that the cause is this line in the `websockets` library code:
`self.logger: LoggerLike = logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, {"websocket": self})`

Then every time the library does `self.logger.info(..)` because of the extra `websocket: self` I get the circular reference.
What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: Please provide an [m.r.e.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, note that the error is "Circular reference" and not a circular import.